# Tkinter window Completly freeze when you move it

Tags: python, tkinter, freeze

The window of Tkinter just completly freeze with all the widgets when I move the Tkinter window and that's my problem I tested it with another code and it always does the same thing

Is the problem exclusively with tkinter?

just move your tkinter window from left to right you will see that absolutely all the program freeze it's incredible

Someone said **to put main in a separated thread** but how ? Like without example I don't even know what It means :(

how do you put the threads outside of mainloop() ? What does it mean ? I putted `root.mainloop()` before the `thread1 = threading.Thread(target= lambda : fct(), daemon=True) thread1.start()` and it does nothing

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 
import time
import threading
import win32api
import pyautogui 



root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x438')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg='gray')


label = Label(root, text='Display content', fg='yellow', bg='black', font=('Arial', 13), width=20)
label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.3)




firstentryvar = StringVar()
secondentryvar = StringVar()



firstentry = Entry(root, textvariable=firstentryvar , justify=CENTER, font = ('Arial', 12))
secondentry = Entry(root, textvariable=secondentryvar, justify=CENTER, font = ('Arial', 12))





def displaycontent(*args): 

    firstentry.pack()
    secondentry.pack()
    label.bind('<Button-1>', hidecontent)



def hidecontent(*args): 

    firstentry.pack_forget()
    secondentry.pack_forget()
    label.bind('<Button-1>', displaycontent)

    


label.bind('<Button-1>', displaycontent)

def function1(*args): 
     count = 0
     bool = False
     while count < 10: 
         
            for i in firstentry.get(): 
                if bool == False: 
                    count +=1 
                    print(i)
                    bool = True
                else: 
                    bool = False
              


def function2(*args): 
   while True: 
    if win32api.GetKeyState(0x45) < 0: 
          
          print('you pressed e')
  
    

thread1 = threading.Thread(target = lambda : function1(), daemon=True)
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target = lambda : function2(), daemon=True)
thread2.start()


   
root.mainloop()
```

the code may not mean much but it's enough to reproduce my example, well you will notice that if you click on the display label and then move the window without entering anything in the entries the window will bug/freeze why?

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you provide a code example and state what system and versions you are using.

Comment: can you provide us some code or at least a minimal reproduction of this? There must be something wrong with the code or that system memory is not enough that it freeze the process. As long as you do it right, you can make the window jump like a bunny without any problem at all

Comment: Ok l'll provide the code edit : that's a problem if i'm not working with classes ?

Comment: As we had discussed yesterday. Your threads are blocking your `mainloop` you need to put the blocking code outside of the `mainloop`. In addition you need great care when interacting with tkinter from outside the thread where tkinters `mainloop` is running.

Comment: but how do you put them outside of mainloop() ? edit : I'll try something i'm not sure

Comment: Thingamabobs is right that's indeed the threads the problem but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a bit with your code and it seems that problem is with your while loops.
Even though you used threads correctly, using while loops this way makes your program uses all the resources to loop into it. What I means is as you started program, even before you press label to show entry widgets, your loops just iterated thousand of times if not tens of thousands.
However, simply putting a time sleep, you can easily stop this exponential resource consuming. However, you shouldn't use time.sleep with tkinter if you aren't using inside threads. As we are using loops inside threads, there is no problem.

For example:

```
def function1(*args): 
    count = 0
    bool = False
    while count < 10:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        for i in firstentry.get(): 
            if bool == False: 
                count +=1 
                print(i)
                bool = True
            else: 
                bool = False
```